# Getting grpc timeout while setting up Hyperledger development environment and network

Tags: go, blockchain, grpc, hyperledger

I followed the docs provided by the hyperledger/fabric documentation. I have setup a network with two validating peers and not CA. I try to run the "peer node status" and "peer network list" command and keep getting the following error:
"Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out trying to connect"

I also tried changing the "maxprocs" to 2 in the core.yaml file, but it still didn't fix the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out trying to connect” usually means that Validation Peer is not started. In default configuration peer process should listen port 30303 and you can easily check that using `netstat -a | grep 30303`

If Validation Peer is started locally, the output should be similar to:

```
tcp6       0      0 [::]:30303              [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

In case if Validation Peer is started in Docker container or on remote VM the IP address should be provided:

```
CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=172.17.0.2:30303 ./peer node status
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the detailed explanation. My Validation peer is starte din a docker ocntainer and I was missing the fact that we have to give the ip addres explicitly when using `peer node status`