# ERRO : Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out trying to connect

Tags: docker, blockchain, hyperledger, docker-toolbox

Unable to deploy chaincode example in my local hyperledger fabric.

system config: mac osx, Docker toolbox for mac

One validating peer is up and running using docker-compose.yaml

```
membersrvc:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
  command: membersrvc
vp0:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
  environment:
    - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=false
    - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=http://172.17.0.1:2375
    - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
    - CORE_PEER_ID=vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLID=test_vp0
    - CORE_SECURITY_ENROLLSECRET=MwYpmSRjupbT
  links:
    - membersrvc
  command: sh -c "sleep 5; peer node start --peer-chaincodedev"
```

While deploying chaincode by running

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30303 ./test
```

Its showing the error as **[shim] ERRO : Error trying to connect to local peer: grpc: timed out trying to connect**

I tried replacing CORE_PEER_ADDRESS as suggested by [grep timeout solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017236/getting-grpc-timeout-while-setting-up-hyperledger-development-environment-and-ne) but no change in error.

[First Validating peer output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuZfV.png)

[Chaincode deployment error window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izDmB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the correct port number on which peer process is listening to.

instead of using the following command,

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:30303 ./test
```

try this instead,

```
CORE_CHAINCODE_ID_NAME=mycc CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052 ./test
```

if it doesn't work then run the following command to check your listening port and use that instead,

```
netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For me the port was 50250